# Tru bolt classic I’m installing this digital door knob

Tags: doors, lock

I get it all installed and the outside lever doesn’t work, it moves but the doesn’t move the bolt. Anyone know why?

Comment: We need a lot more information to give you a useful answer. Please edit your question to include a brand and model name, as well as a photo. Your photo can also include drawings or labels that indicate the problem areas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't programmed an entry code yet, enter 1-2-3-4 and press the Unlock icon in the lower right. The outside lever will now move the bolt because the device is unlocked. When the device is locked, the lever moves, but it does not engage the bolt.